# How to use #each in an array of arrays in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js

In Ember.js documentation, it only shows how to show an array of objects using `#each` like this:

Suppose you have this array of objects:

```
var arr1 = [
    {name: 'Name 1', color: 'red'},
    {name: 'Name 2', color: 'yellow'},
    {name: 'Name 3', color: 'green'},
];
```

You would use something like this to show the names:

```
{{#each arr1}}
    {{name}}
{{/each}}
```

But, I have this array of arrays like this:

```
var arr2 = [
    ["Name 1", "red"],
    ["Name 2", "yellow"],
    ["Name 3", "green"],
];
```

The question is: How do I use `#each` to show the value of index `0` of the variable `arr2`?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `{{#each}}` inside `{{#each}}`:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vajolene/2/edit

```
  {{#each this}}
    {{#each this}}
      {{this}}
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
```